# Python: environment variables in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, environment-variables

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-cygwin', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

question :

I have installed python in windows and set sys path, ithusI can run python with command line but why the sys.path doesn't right, it's like a Linux `env` path

Comment: i don't have '/usr/lib/python27.zip' path in win 10, what's wrong with that and what can i do to solve it

Comment: I believe, internally, Python uses the forward slash (Unix-style path separator) for all paths. `sys.path` is where Python looks for modules by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) is not related to `PATH` environment variable. It specifies search path for python modules.

You should check [`os.environ['PATH']`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) (or `os.path.environ.get('PATH')`) to check `PATH` environment variable.

---

search paths are looks like linux path because you're using cygwin version of Python, instead of native windows version. (You can find one from [Python releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/))

Comment: thank you very much ， i use native windows command line and the result is true